# Why do some webpages print nicer than others?

Tags: html, css

When I print webpages, say for github and usually all the ones done in wordpress.. all the formatting goes away. Whilst other pages, For example http://webnoir.org/tutorials/forms has kept their formatting. Also, I noticed that sometimes pages with a black background prints with a white background, and other times I end up wasting half my printer's toner. Is there a way to set this using css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print style sheet

[10 Tips for Better Print Style Sheets](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/01/10-tips-for-better-print-style-sheets/)

"In case you’ve forgotten, here’s how to set up a print style sheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

The `media="print"` attribute ensures that users don’t see any of the styles defined in the print.css file.
Some attention is required, though: if your main style sheet has no media attribute, the print style sheet will inherit its style ..."

Answer (score 1):

You can add conditional styles for print like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

Styling a page for print has its own intricacies, so it's worth reading through this [ALA Article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/).

Comment: It's because (as shown above) different media can use different style sheets. Styling for printing will allow the page to be altered to be printed.